# SSRS - Passing Date/Time Parameter Value to Stored Procedure = No data available

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

In my report users can select a **Date/Time parameter (date)** to filter the data in their report.

To get the data from the database I use a **stored procedure with parameters**, so the **Date/Time parameter value** is passed through to the stored procedure.

When the user selects a date and runs the report it only shows **"No data available"**.

So I checked the **ExecutionLog3** how the date parameter is passed through. 
The date is formatted "**mm/dd/yyyy** hh:mm:ss" (**01/14/2014** 00:00:00 - It's January 14).

When I execute the stored procedure with **01/14/2014 00:00:00** as date parameter directly, I also get no data. But when I change the date to **14/01/2014 00:00:00** or **14.01.2014 00:00:00** everything works fine. So I guess the problem is, that SSRS uses the **US date format** when it sends the date parameter value to the stored procedure.

Things I tried so far:

- Opened the data set which uses the stored procedure and changed the Parameter Value for date to `CDate(Parameters!date.Value)`
- Changed the `SELECT` Statement in the data set which is used to **fill the date Parameter** with valid dates: `SELECT CONVERT(date, k.date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as date` (Here I get a "nvarchar to date" conversion error)

It would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: What is the datatype of the database column and the SP parameter?

Comment: Can you change the format of the parameter in the SP to the desired format? So in the SP itself I mean.

Comment: @DanBracuk database column = date & SP parameter = date

Comment: @NickyvV No, this is not possible.

Comment: If both the database column and paramter type are date, as they should be, then the format is irrelevent.

Comment: Try adding a second parameter and set its value to be:     =Format(Parameters!DateTimeParameter.Value, "yyyy-MM-dd") - use this param in your selection instead
 This is only a workaround, though, to get your report working while you fix the issue

Comment: @DanBracuk it depends on the localization of the database and SSRS/VS I believe

Comment: When I execute the SP in my SQL Management Studio I have to insert the date parameter as String, like '14/01/2014 00:00:00'. When I insert '01/14/2014 00:00:00' in my query, like I wrote above, I get no data. When SSRS calls the SP, maybe the date parameter is also converted into a String (-> '01/14/2014 00:00:00') and this is the reason I get no data in my report?

Answer (score 2):

The issue is based on the formatting of date values by the database.  You can set the date format at the database level by using the Set DateFormat command.  I don't believe this is what you want to do though.  It sounds like you want SSRS to pass in the correct format to the database.

To do that, change the parameter value you are passing in to your data set to be the following expression:

```
=Format(Parameters!date.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```